# Using command line to see if a given computer's local guest account is disabled

Tags: command-line-interface, powershell, user-management, sox

I need to generate a report that shows the guest account is disabled for a given list of computers.

How can I use `net user`, powershell, or any other commonly used tool for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little PowerShell function to check for this.

```
function Test-LocalAccountDisabled
{
    param (
        [string]
        $AccountName = 'Guest',
        [string[]]
        $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    $AccountDisable=0x0002
    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)
    {
        [ADSI]$Guest="WinNT://$Computer/$AccountName,User"
        if ($Guest -ne $null)
        {
            New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Disabled = ($Guest.UserFlags.Value -band $AccountDisable) -as [boolean]
                AccountName = $AccountName
                ComputerName = $Computer
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Error "Unable to find $AccountName on $Computer."
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a list of computers in a text file separated by line breaks, you could do something like

```
Test-LocalAccountDisabled -ComputerName (get-content computers.txt)
```

Comment: I like this one but it doesn't display output on my PC

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?  V1, V2, or V3?

Comment: 2.0 on Win7  via `function Ver { get-host | select version }`

Comment: Interesting.  I do get output objects on my Win 7 test machine.  How are you trying to call the function?

Comment: hmm this works: `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Computer hostname -Filter "LocalAccount='$true'"|Select-Object Name,Disabled|Format-Table -AutoSize`  .. do you know how I can have 2 filter statements? `&&` doesn't work.   I'd like to add the "name" parameter?

Comment: the filter is a wql query, so you have to use "and"  It would look like "LocalAccount='$true' and Name like 'Guest'"

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is probably the easiest way:

```
foreach ( $computer in (Get-Content computers.txt) ) {
  Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Computer $computer -Filter "Name = 'guest'" `
    | Select-Object __Server, Disabled
}
```

Using `wmic` in batch is ugly, but will work as well:

```
set query=useraccount where name^^="guest" get disabled

for /f %c in ('computers.txt') do (
  for /f "delims== tokens=2" %a in ('wmic /node:%c %query% /value') do (
    echo %c %a
  )
)
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I suggested a couple of edits (adding __Server to know what machine the account status was coming from in the case of checking multiples and using the pipe as the line continuation rather than the backtick.

Comment: @StevenMurawski Thanks. I'm aware that a pipe at the end of the line would automatically continue the line, but I prefer to escape the line break and put the pipe at the beginning of the next line. That way I can see immediately where a command is continued from the previous line. I didn't know about `__Server`, though. Thanks for the tip, that's much more convenient than `@{n=computer;e={$computer}}`.

Comment: You bet.  The backtick at the end of the line can sometimes throw people off, so that's why I recommended that change.  No worries.  Rather than using the foreach, you could just pass the whole (Get-Content computers.txt) to the -computername parameter.  That would let all the queries go at once rather than queuing them up in a line.  If you have a number of machines, that will perform better.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  When I manually type `Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Computer nycexhc01 -Filter "Name = 'guest'" | fl` there is no "disabled" property, and I also get the local machine and domain guest account for each query.

Answer (score 0):

A Powershell script with something like this should do the trick:

```
$Servers = Get-Content "C:\Path\To\File\With\Servers.txt"

foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -computername $Server -filter "LocalAccount=True AND` 
    Name='Guest'" | Select-Object Domain,Name,Disabled
}
```

This will read in a list of server names from a text file, and loop through them displaying an entry for each disabled guest account.  If you take out `AND Name=Guest`, it will show you all disabled accounts on each machine.

Comment: Steve,  rather than using the foreach, you can pass all the computer names to the -computername parameter.  You could add __Server to the output so that the user knows which machine the account report is coming from.

Comment: Ahh.. yes.  You are correct!

Comment: I don't have a disabled property for any server I query.